# Error while installing Sqlite3 on Raspberry Pi

Tags: sqlite, raspberry-pi

Trying to install Sqlite3 on Raspberry Pi but not able to install.

```
pi@raspberrypi:/etc/apt $ sudo apt-get install sqlite3 --fix-missing
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libgssapi3-heimdal libheimntlm0-heimdal libxfce4ui-1-0 xfce-keyboard-shortcuts
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
Suggested packages:
  sqlite3-doc
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  sqlite3
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 56 not upgraded.
Need to get 99.6 kB of archives.
After this operation, 139 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie/main sqlite3 armhf 3.8.7.1-1+deb8u2 [99.6 kB]
Fetched 1,946 B in 6s (312 B/s)
E: Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/s/sqlite3/sqlite3_3.8.7.1-1+deb8u2_armhf.deb  Size mismatch

E: Internal Error, ordering was unable to handle the media swap
```

Comment: Apparently, some package mirror has a wrong file. Accident, or NSA?

Comment: @CL. : Can you please provide more details on how to fix this issue.